# How to style conditionally ul element

Tags: html, css

I would like to to apply a different style to `ul`, if within its `li` there is a `input` tag

So the first list should look different from the second one.
How to achieve this in regular CSS with no JS?

---

```html
<ul>
    <li><input disabled="" type="checkbox"> Item unchecked</li>
    <li><input checked="" disabled="" type="checkbox"> Item checked</li>
</ul>
```

---

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item unchecked</li>
    <li>Item checked</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can't with css only

Comment: You cannot target parent with CSS yet so you will need javascript for this particular problem.

Comment: There is a `:has()` selector in the CSS4 draft which would let you inspect child elements in a selector, but [no browsers support it yet](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has).